# How to use AVG(field) in select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

The question I'm trying to solve is:

List all staff whose salary is less than the average salary and list by how much.

The Tables in questions:

```
CREATE TABLE Staff
    (`staffNo` varchar(4), `fName` varchar(5), `lName` varchar(5), 
     `position` varchar(10), `sex` varchar(1), `DOB` varchar(9), 
     `salary` int, `branchNo` varchar(4))
;   

INSERT INTO Staff
    (`staffNo`, `fName`, `lName`, `position`, `sex`, `DOB`, `salary`, `branchNo`)
VALUES
    ('SL21', 'John', 'White', 'Manager', 'M', '1-Oct-45', 30000, 'B005'),
    ('SG37', 'Ann', 'Beech', 'Assistant', 'F', '10-Nov-60', 12000, 'B003'),
    ('SG14', 'David', 'Ford', 'Supervisor', 'M', '24-Mar-58', 18000, 'B003'),
    ('SA9', 'Mary', 'Howe', 'Assistant', 'F', '19-Feb-70', 9000, 'B007'),
    ('SG5', 'Susan', 'Brand', 'Manager', 'F', '3-Jun-40', 24000, 'B003'),
    ('SL41', 'Julie', 'Lee', 'Assistant', 'F', '13-Jun-65', 9000, 'B005')
;
```

The solution I have been working on is:

```
SELECT s.staffNo, s.fName, s.lName, s.salary
FROM Staff s
WHERE s.salary < (SELECT AVG(s.salary) FROM *)
ORDER BY s.salary DESC;
```

This works however it doesn't answer the final section of the question, "...and list by how much."

I had though to incorporate it like this:

```
SELECT staffNo, fName, lName, salary, (30000-salary) as Average
FROM Staff
WHERE salary < (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM Staff)
ORDER BY salary DESC;
```

But that only gives an error....

Any help you can offer here?

Comment: If something gives an error, then include the actual error in your question.

Comment: I have also edited your question: please use code blocks were appropriate, instead of using back ticks (which is for inline code formatting). It will lead to more readable code (syntax highlighting).

Comment: Thanks Mark. I tried to add code block but could only see the inline code markup button? (I just looked again at the edits and see that it is 4 indents then saw the code block option...don't know how i missed it,apologies)

Also, the error was from the SQL Fiddle site as I am still waiting for the SQL server to install on my PC but the error was generic..sorry and thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join with a subquery that returns the average salary

```
SELECT staffNo, fName, lName, salary, avgSalary-salary AS salaryDiff, avgSalary
FROM Staff
JOIN (SELECT AVG(salary) AS avgSalary
      FROM Staff) AS av
ON salary < avgSalary
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03a3b/2)

Comment: Thanks Barmar. 

Im confised as to what the av in:
"JOIN (SELECT AVG(salary) AS avgSalary FROM Staff) AS av"
is for? 

I was at the point of the JOIN statement before checking back but couldn't quite get there...thank you:)

Comment: @JCrombie A subselect needs an alias to be referenced. Technically you should use that alias when referencing columns from that subselect (eg `av.avgSalary`), but as there is no ambiguity, you can leave it out, but the engine still requires an alias.

Comment: Thanks Mark, makes perfect sense now.